# Diffrence between calling function from destructor or giving it to atexit()

Tags: c++, constructor, atexit

I am little confused about this — please help.

Suppose a C++ program has a single class and a single object of that class.
I want to perform some cleanup related task and have written a function for that. 
Then should I prefer calling that method from destructor or calling through `atexit()`?

Note: I know the purpose of C++ class destructors and `atexit()`. Will it affect any performance? Or any benefits?

Answer (score 2):

`atexit()` register a function to be called when the program terminates (e.g. when `main()` calls a `return` or when `exit()` is explicitly called somewhere).

It helps you guarantee that some procedure will be performed every time the program terminates, regardless of where the termination was invoked.

When `exit()` is invoked, static objects are destroyed (destructor is called), but not objects in local variable scope and of course dynamically allocated objects neither (those are only destroyed if you explicitly call `delete`).

If your objects are not static, you may want to register a `atexit()` function to guarantee that your clean up procedure will be performed, otherwise that will be done automatically.

That is, if your program uses `exit()` at all. If your code is designed so that `main()` will always terminate normally, you can just place your code there.

Comment: Thanks Havenard.I just tried When we use atexit() destructor of local object and dynamic objects wont be invoked.